# Java Arrays being overwritten

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, jtextfield

Hey I'm a little new here so my apologies if I messed something up in my post. Anyways the problem I'm having has to deal with arrays, what I'm trying to do basically is use the *String[]* arrays to populate my form and display it on screen and then have the **getForm()** function return a **String[]** with the title of the form and the info in **text[i]**. This all works fine until I use use the button I added to call the **getForm()** function and I change to a different form (**createForm()** attached to ListListener) and all the labels appear as whatever was returned in the **getForm()** function. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the way I'm using my arrays but I thought they would be set back to normal after I chose another list item which goes through the **createForm()** function again resetting the arrays, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Thanks

I've included a screenshot of what I'm referring too bellow as well.

http://www.majhost.com/gallery/adc90/afsd/error.png

```
class Form extends JPanel
{
    //Arrays for the forms
    private String[] com = {"Communication","ICAO","Type","Frequency"};
    private String[] fuel = {"Fuel","ICAO","Type"};
    private String[] runway = {"Runway","ICAO","Number","Type","Length"};
    private String[] airplane = {"Airplane","Make","Model","Type","Fuel Capacity", "Fuel Burn Rate", "Air Speed"};
    private String[] airport = {"Airplane","ICAO","Name","Longitude","Latitude","crFreq","crType", "Fuel Type"};

    //Declare variables
    private JTextField[] text;
    private String[] formReturn;
    private String[] formArray;
    private JButton submit,clear;

    public Form()
    {
        createForm("Airplane");
    }

    public void createForm(String choice)
    {
        removeAll();
        if(choice.equals("Communication"))
        {
            formArray = com;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("Fuel"))
        {
            formArray = fuel;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("Airplane"))
        {
            formArray = airplane;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("Airport"))
        {
            formArray = airport;
        }
        else if(choice.equals("Runway"))
        {
            formArray = runway;
        }


        int l = formArray.length + 1;
        text = new JTextField[l];

        //Layout info
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(l,2);
        grid.setHgap(0);
        setLayout(grid);
        //Set label
        add(new JLabel(formArray[0]));
        add(new JLabel(""));
        for(int i = 1; i < formArray.length; ++i)
        {
            add(new JLabel(formArray[i]));
            add(text[i] = new JTextField(20));
        }

        //Add in the buttons and the actionlisteners
        submit = new JButton("Create");
        clear = new JButton("Delete");
        add(clear);
            clear.addActionListener(new Button());
        add(submit);
            submit.addActionListener(new Button());
        updateUI();
    }
    //Get form info
    //This works so far
    public String[] getForm()
    {
        formReturn = formArray;
        formReturn[0] = formArray[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < formReturn.length; i++)
            formReturn[i] = text[i].getText();
        return formReturn;
    }
    //Clear form
    public void clearForm()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < formArray.length; i++)
            text[i].setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String[] getForm()
{
    formReturn = formArray; /* (0) */
    formReturn[0] = formArray[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < formReturn.length; i++)
        formReturn[i] = text[i].getText(); /* (1) */
    return formReturn;
}
```

Look at line (1): you modify formReturn array which points to labels text. formReturn -> formArray -> com.

To fix it just create new String array at (0):

```
formReturn = new String[formArray.length];
```

Comment: It works great now I don't see how I didn't see that before. Thanks so much.